# Cookie are set but code not working

Tags: php, cookies, popup, session-cookies

I've been trying to set this up for a while but i can't seem to get it right. My goal is to make the newsletter appear once only if the user hasn't visited the site. The problem i run into is that the cookie is set but the pop up is still showing. I have looked all over stackoverflow and i've been tweaking code but can't seem to make it work. Any ideas why?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
    setcookie('visited', true, time() + 3600 * 24); // Save a cookie for 1 day
?>
    <div class="newsletter_pop">
        <div class="pop-contain">
            <p class="close-new-pop">x</p>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')>setTemplate('newsletter/pop.newsletter.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
         </div>
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.newsletter_pop').fadeIn();
            $('.close-new-pop').click(function(){
                $('.newsletter_pop').fadeOut();
            }); 
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any code there that ever stops the popup.

Comment: I don't see where you actually check to see if the cookie is set. You just always show the pop up.

Comment: have you thought of using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` ?

Comment: @JohnConde, the javascript (for the popup) seems to be inside the if-statement that checks if the cookie isn't set. So that would mean that once the cookie is set the javascript shouldn't be outputted to the browser.

Comment: @TomUdding I'm not sure where you see that. I don't see any JavaScript that checks for the value of *any* cookie.

Comment: @JohnConde I mean that the javascript is inside the PHP if-statement, if the cookies is indeed set it shouldn't output everything (including the javascript) inside the if-statement (that is at least what my PHP parser does).

Comment: That's not javascript, that's PHP. It's also just setting the cookie. The problem is they never check the cookie for its value *anywhere*.

Comment: @JohnConde I checked the cookies value but its still the same nothing changes